# How to automatically add JS/CSS to HTML files?

Tags: html, webpack

Is there a way to have Webpack scan Javascript files for `require("file.js")` and `require("file.css")` and insert `<script type="text/javascript">` and `<link rel="stylesheet">` (respectively) to any HTML file that includes the root Javascript file?

For example. Given:

### Main.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
[...]
```

### Main.js

```
require("./login.js");
require("./login.css");
```

I expect to get this output:

### Main.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="login.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
[...]
```

Bonus points: ability to `require("login.scss")` and end up with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="login.css"/>` (meaning, take into consideration the fact that SCSS files will get converted to CSS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the author of Webpack, this feature does not exist yet.

I have filed this feature request: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/754

Answer (score 0):

i have created a little python script that allows me to import files(.js, .css, .younameit) from a directory to the html.

before:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- {SVN_AUTO_IMPORT type:.js; dir:../tsc_out; exclude:; template:<script src="%PATH"</script>;} -->
    </head>
```

after:

```
<html>
   <head>
     <script src="../tsc_out/script1.js"></script>
    <script src="../tsc_out/script2.js"></script>
    <script src="../tsc_out/script3.js"></script>
    <script src="../tsc_out/script4.js"></script>
    <script src="../tsc_out/script5.js"></script>
  </head>
```

https://github.com/seven-jerry/html-importer

Comment: Link only answers are frowned upon because links can become broken. Please try to summarize the relevant portions of what is found within the link here. The user can go to that link for more information if need be.